# Measuring latency

Tags: java, networking

I'm working on a multiplayer project in Java and I am trying to refine how I gather my latency measurement results.

My current setup is to send a batch of UDP packets at regular intervals that get timestamped by the server and returned, then latency is calculated and recorded. I take number of samples then work out the average to get the latency.

Does this seem like a reasonable solution to work out the latency on the client side?

Comment: I assume all your communication is done using UDP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also timestamp packets used in your game protocol . So you will have more data to integrate your statistics. (This method is also useful to avoid the overhead caused by an additional burst of data. You simply used the data you are already exchanging to do your stats)

You could also start to use other metrics (for example variance) in order to make a more accurate estimation of your connection quality.

Comment: Hi 0verbose, I like this idea, but I guess the problem would be that every packet would require a response sort of doubling the traffic I guess?

Comment: @TechyAdam: the more "timestamps" you collect, more accurate are your stats. Of course sending a lot of unused packet just for collecting stats is not a good idea. Yes, of course a packet would require an immediate response to be useful. Anyway it could be just an ack packet sent back to the client, with a small dimension an containing only the timestamp,a packet sequence number and few datas like that.

Comment: @TechyAdam: but in answering to you i thought that you was already sending back to the client some sort of UDP ack datagram, because UDP is not reliable and so you need at least some ack to be sure that packets sent before reached the destination.

Comment: @ 0verbose indeed I am, but at general intervals. I like this idea, and like you said I'll have more information to base my results on. Thanks.

Comment: Getting time stamp from one party and checking its time stamp with another party's timestamp didn't work out well for me because it was hard to synchronize two party's clock. Using NPE's answer below worked better for me.

Answer (score 15):

I would have the client timestamp the outgoing packet, and have the response preserve the original timestamp. This way you can compute the roundtrip latency while side-stepping any issues caused by the server and client clocks not being exactly synchronized.

Comment: thanks. time synchronization was exactly my problem. My two windows OS clocks were synchronized with internet clock, but for some reason they are still off by about 3 seconds so i couldn't really find one way latency. Your way works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't really started your project yet, consider using a networking framework like [KryoNet](http://code.google.com/p/kryonet/), which has RMI and efficient serialisation and which will automatically send ping requests using UDP. You can get the ping time values easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you are measuring roundtrip latency, factors like clock drift, precision of HW clock and OS api would affect your measurement. Without spending money on the hardware the closest that you can get is by using RDTSC instructions. But RDTSC doesnt go without its own problems, you have to be careful how you call it.